# How to run command in XAMPP to run OpenOffice in headless mode

Tags: shell, command-line, xampp, openoffice.org, phpdocx

I have purchased PHPDOCX PRO+ plugin. I am trying to Transform Docx to PDF but for that it requires to run OpenOffice in headless mode. OpenOffice Library is already bundled in PHPDocx.
I am using XAMPP server on Windows 7.
The command to run OpenOffice in Headless mode is :

$ lib/openoffice/openoffice.org3/program/soffice -headless -accept=”socket,host=127.0.0.1,port=8100;urp;” -nofirststartwizard

But i don't know how to run this command in Xampp. I tried Shell Command line of Xampp but it doesn't worked.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the command you provided, it seem that you didn't reference the right path for soffice. The correct format in windows should be:

```
C:\path\to\openoffice\program\soffice -headless
-accept=”socket,host=127.0.0.1,port=8100;urp;” -nofirststartwizard
```

Just insert this command in the CMD and it should work.